# Input writing to output file multiple times (C)

Tags: c, file, file-io, output, scanf

I am trying to make a program that takes user input and writes to an output file, but I am encountering an odd error where the output is being scanned multiple times.

This is my code:

```
void firstTime(){


char name[20], animal[30], bday[8];
  char initializedGameState[1];
  initializedGameState[0] = '1';
  printf("Hello and welcome to the program! Please complete this quick first time setup.\n");
  printf("Please enter your name:\n");
  scanf("%s", &name);
  printf("\nPlease enter your birthdate (formatted MMDDYYYY):\n");
  scanf("%s", &bday);
  printf("\nHello %s, please choose a favorite animal:\n", name);
  scanf("%s", &animal);

  printf("\n");

  FILE *fp;
  fp = fopen("persistence.txt", "w");
  if(fp == NULL) printf("persistence.txt has failed to open.");
  else{
    fputs(name, fp);
    fputs("\n", fp);
    fputs(bday, fp);
    fputs("\n", fp);
    fputs(animal, fp);
    fputs("\n", fp);
    fputs(initializedGameState, fp);
    fputs("\n", fp);
    fclose(fp);
    printf("First time setup complete. Initializing Detox.me...\n");
    setGameState(1);
  }
}
```

Yet after putting input, this is the output:

```
john
04011998dog
dog
104011998dog
```

while it should be:

```
john
04011998
dog
1
```

Thanks

Comment: Note that `initializedGameState` is not a string (no null terminator).  You can’t legitimately write it with `fputs()`.  Trying to do so may lead to some other information being reprinted.  You also haven’t allowed enough space for the birth date either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
fputs(initializedGameState, fp);
```

`initializedGameState` is not a null-terminated string, so the "string" continues to the previous variables (`bday` and `animal`).

Change the initialization to:

```
char initializedGameState[2]; // note that you need 2 characters
initializedGameState[0] = '1';
initializedGameState[1] = '\0';
```

Comment: And `bday` isn’t long enough to hold an 8-digit number and the terminating null, also leading to trouble.